# Let a user delete a imageview

Tags: android, imageview

Is there a way to allow a user to delete an imageview if it already has a on touch listener being used for drag and drop? Is there another way to delete one when a user wants too?
This is my on drop listener at the moment. How can I tell if I drop in a certain area to delete?

```
private final class myListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layparms = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                xCoord = x - layparms.leftMargin;
                yCoord = y - layparms.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xCoord;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y - yCoord;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Have a specific "delete" drop target. You can see this on many home screen implementations, where starting a drag-and-drop of a launcher icon will either create a shortcut or perform a specific action (like "delete") if the user drops the icon over a specific drop target.

Comment: How would I be able to tell if it is dropped over a certain area?

Comment: Put a view there, set up to be a drop target (e.g., call `setOnDragListener()` on it). Only show that view during a drag-and-drop operation, hiding it when the operation ends. Again, if you think of a home screen, the "Delete" or "App Info" or whatever only show up when the user is dragging and dropping.

Comment: How would I only show it during a drag?

Comment: I am assuming that by drag-and-drop you mean [Android's drag-and-drop framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). If so, you would show those views when you start the drag via `startDrag()` (or `startDragAndDrop()` on Android N+), and you would hide them again when they receive the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` event.

Comment: I've put my listener above, where would it fit in with this?

Comment: I have no idea. You do not seem to be using [Android's drag-and-drop framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). You appear to be rolling your own drag-and-drop mechanism. That's fine, but you wrote the code, so you should know when you are starting and ending the drag-and-drop operation.

Comment: So ACTION_DOWN registers when the view is pressed so here I should make the delete view visible and then on ACTION_MOVE which registers a movement in between DOWN and UP I should check if the moved view is dropped over the target view. Have I missed anything?

Comment: That's tough for me to say, but it sounds like a good starting point.